# Entity Framework Relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a model for Users and definition is

```
public class User
{
    public string UserID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FullName {
        get
        {
            return (FirstName + " " + LastName).Trim();
        }
    }
    public string EmailID { get; set; }
    public UserAccessLabel AccessLabel { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string PasswordStore {
        get
        {
            string hashPass;
            using (Encryption enc = new Encryption())
            {
                enc.Key = EncryptionKey.DefaultKey;
                hashPass = enc.Encrypt(Password);
            }
            return hashPass;
        }
        set
        {
            string hashPass;
            using (Encryption enc = new Encryption())
            {
                enc.Key = EncryptionKey.DefaultKey;
                hashPass = enc.Decrypt(value);
            }
            Password = hashPass;
        }
    }
    public byte[] Image { get; set;}
}
```

and fluentAPI configuration class is

```
public class UserConfig : EntityTypeConfiguration<User>
{
    public UserConfig()
    {
        ToTable("tblUsers");
        HasKey(k => k.UserID);
        Property(p => p.FirstName).IsRequired();
        Property(p => p.LastName).IsRequired();
        Property(p => p.PasswordStore).IsRequired().HasColumnName("Password");
        Property(p => p.Image).HasColumnType("image");
        Ignore(i => i.FullName);
        Ignore(i => i.Password);
    }
}
```

And i have lots of other model like Products, Category, Customers etc. and every model has **Created** and **Updated** property, which are users.

And my questions is, do I have to create all models collection property in **User** Model ?

something like

```
public ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }



 public class ProductConfig:EntityTypeConfiguration<Product>
{
    public ProductConfig()
    {
        ToTable("tblProducts");
        HasKey(k => k.Code);
        Property(p => p.Title).IsRequired();
        Property(p => p.Title).HasMaxLength(100);


        HasRequired(c => c.Category).WithMany(p => p.Products).HasForeignKey(f => f.CategoryID).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        HasRequired(u => u.Created).WithMany(p => p.Products).HasForeignKey(f => f.CreatedUser).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        HasRequired(u => u.Updated).WithMany(p => p.Products).HasForeignKey(f => f.UpdatedUser).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
}
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need these collections, you don't have to. It's enough to have FK properties on these entities and have corresponding DbSet properties in your DbContext.

**Update**

If you mean that the FK id column is not empty but the object field is `null`, this is because they are not loaded by default. You can load them by calling extension method `Include` like this

```
context.Products.Include("Created")
```

Comment: but i am not able to access data from foreign key column, data exist there in database when i check it by using simple sql query as like Created_UserID but in model it showing null in created property under Product Model

Comment: If you mean that the FK id column is not empty but the object field is null, this is because they are not loaded by default. You can load them by calling extension method `Include` like this
`context.Products.Include("Created")`

Comment: Yeah this were the answer i was looking for. Thank you very much

Comment: Ok, added it to the answer

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to do is make a one to many relationship in your code first database. `public ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }` is the correct syntax for making each `user` the owner of *many* `products`. Then in the products model file you would include a foreign key to it's user.

```
public class Product
{
    public virtual User ProductsUser {get; set;}
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Comment: it means I have to create something like

`
    public ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Vendor> Vendors{ get; set; }
    public ICollection<Customer> Customers{ get; set; }
`
in user model